# PANDAS - using map and ignore case sensitivity

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data-frames:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Item': ["jetties","Jetty", "Joint use"], 'Team': ["Team_1", "Team_2", "Team_1"]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Item': ["Jetty","Jetties","Joint use"]})
```

I am applying map to return Team values in df2:

```
df2['Team'] = df2['Item'].map(df1.set_index('Item')['Team'])
```

[image]

However, the result is giving me Nan for Jetties because of case sensitivity.
Is there any way to ignore case sensitivity?

Answer (score 1):

You can convert your key to a defined case:

```
df2['Team'] = (df2['Item'].str.lower()
               .map(df1.assign(Item=df1['Item'].str.lower())
                       .set_index('Item')['Team'])
              )
```

output:

```
        Item    Team
0      Jetty  Team_2
1    Jetties  Team_1
2  Joint use  Team_1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on=df1['Item'].str.lower(), right_on=df2['Item'].str.lower(), how='left').drop(['key_0', 'Item_x'], axis=1).rename(columns={'Item_y': 'Item'})
df = df[['Item', 'Team']]
df
```

I prefer joining data to using map most of the time

Answer (score 0):

Extending on mozway's answer, it is probably better to call the assign function as follows. This will facilitate to refactor the logic into a function at a later point if necessary.

```
df2["Team"] = ( 
    df2["Item"]
    .str.lower()
    .map(df1.assign(**{"Item": df1["Item"].str.lower()}).set_index("Item")["Team"])
)
```

For example

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    "Item": ["jetties", "Jetty", "Joint use"],
    "Team": ["Team_1", "Team_2", "Team_1"]
})
print("df1")
print(df1)

df2 = pd.DataFrame({"Item": ["Jetty", "Jetties", "Joint use"]})
print("df2")
print(df2)


def map_series(s, df, key_col, value_col, ignore_case):
    if ignore_case:
        result = s.str.lower().map(
            df.assign(**{key_col: df[key_col].str.lower()})
              .set_index(key_col)[value_col]
        )
    else:
        result = s.map(df.set_index(key_col)[value_col])
    return result


df2["Team_include_case"] = map_series(
    df2["Item"], df1, "Item", "Team", ignore_case=False
)
df2["Team_ignore_case"] = map_series(
    df2["Item"], df1, "Item", "Team", ignore_case=True
)
print("after mapping")
print(df2)
```

Sample output

```
df1
        Item    Team
0    jetties  Team_1
1      Jetty  Team_2
2  Joint use  Team_1
df2
        Item
0      Jetty
1    Jetties
2  Joint use
after mapping
        Item Team_include_case Team_ignore_case
0      Jetty            Team_2           Team_2
1    Jetties               NaN           Team_1
2  Joint use            Team_1           Team_1
```